# Connecting to redis from kubernetes cluster application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I setup a redis instance (the google managed "memory store") in the same region as I deployed my kubernetes cluster. I expected that I could simply use this private redis ip address as `host` to connect from an application which is deployed in the kubernetes cluster. Unfortunately I always get `etimedout` and I have absolutely no idea anymore what I would need to do, to connect to the memory store.

Do I need to add special firewall rules or am I missing something in the process? I haven't setup any custom rules, it's all default.

Comment: are you using the default network? Also, are you using a [VPC-Native cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips) for GKE? If not, your pods may have trouble routing traffic to internal IPs outside the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was trouble with network created via terraform. There is no option to ip aliasing. Memorystore should be at your vpc (as peer) and your cluster must be created with ip aliasing, as said in docs. 
In my case I wrote this:

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "my-cluster" {
...
  ip_allocation_policy = {
    cluster_ipv4_cidr_block = "10.2.0.0/19"
  }
...
}
```

And ip aliasing was setted by default.
I found this solution [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/1597).

Answer (score 0):

most likely you'd have to add a `redis` tag to the network interface, which permits `tcp:6379`.

see https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-redis

in particular, the section "Open the network port (optional)" ...

using Cloud Shell to SSH into such an instance, may help finding the issue.

Comment: I am using the Google managed redis (Memory store) and therefore I can't edit the "network interface" of my redis VM as described in that article.